# VueJS3 - Get handle to element within for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I have a component layout like the following:

```
<div class="list-item" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <div class="sub-item"></div>
</div>
```

The problem I'm having is, how do I grab the handle of that sub-item element on demand? I need to essentially do something like this:

1. Grab the item from the list where item ID = X.
2. Grab the ".sub-item" HTMLElement under the selected item to adjust the elements "style.width" dynamically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing first: you cannot have multiple HTML elements with the same ID (which you are doing with the container and sub item). I guess you want a container, and a `v-for` of children. Put the `v-for` on the child and use Vue element refs on the children (Vue supports creating an array of template refs when used with a `v-for`-ed element).

Comment: My apologies, I don't have it setup that way in my real project, and just now realize this example HTML is invalid for the duplicate ID's as you've suggested. I've updated the example to now be valid but still demonstrates the problem Im having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the element with certain id in your for loop you can use a **condition** inside your **v-for** like this:

```
<div id="container" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
  <div :class="item.id == ID ? 'sub-item change-width-class' : 'sub-item'"></div>
</div>
```

You can listen the timer and change the currentElement by id using a **watcher**:

```
<template>
    <div id="container" v-for="item in items" :key="item.id">
        <div :id="`sub-item-${currentElementId}`></div>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
    import { ref, watch } from 'vue';

    const timer = ref(0);
    const currentElementId = ref(1);

    // every time timer updates the function below will run
    watch(timer, () => {
        const subItem = document.querySelector(`.sub-item-${currentElementId}`);
        subItem.style.width = (100 * timer / 250); 
    });

</script>
```

Comment: This doesn't show how I can dynamically adjust the inner-div's style width programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: How is this change trigged? Can you give an example, like the "the user clicks on an item and the item width is changed"

Comment: There is a background timer updating a value - lets pretend this value is going from 0-250 over 10 seconds. That value needs to be mapped to adjusting the elements width from 0-100%.

Comment: I guess I could map it to a variable in a bound object property and bind it like ":style="{ width: myWidth + 'px' }""...I'll try that.

Comment: Ah, that works! If you like, I'll let you post that as the answer and mark that as the solution since you got me thinking down that path ;).

Comment: Oh thank you, I think I undestand your problem and updated the answer